# Green's third identity potential massive object

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, potential-theory, green-function, laplace-equation

Consider a massive object occupying a volume $U$ with boundary $\partial U$. Let the gravitational potential inside be $V_{in}$ and outside $V_{out}$
Normally the gravitational field of a massive object is solved via an integral of Green's function over the volume of the object.

**Is there a surface integral equation (or equations) for solving the gravitational potential of an object, where the density of the object is given, but the value and derivative of the potential at the surface are unknown?**

I have some guesses as to the forms of these equations (if they exist). Inside we can write 
$$V_{in}=V_L+V_P$$
where $V_L$ solves Laplace's equation and $V_P$ (assumed to be known) solves Poisson's equation.

The boundary conditions for the problem are
$$ V_{in}(\mathbf{r})=V_{out}(\mathbf{r}), \qquad \partial_n V_{in}(\mathbf{r})=\partial_n V_{out}(\mathbf{r}), \qquad \mathbf{r}\in\partial U$$
Where $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit normal to the surface (pointing outwards).

And we have Green's third identity for $V_L$ and $V_{out}$:
$$ \int_{\partial U} G(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'}) \frac{\partial V_L(\mathbf{r'})}{\partial n}  -  V_L(\mathbf{r'}) \frac{\partial G(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'})}{\partial n} \mathrm{d}s = 
\begin{cases} V_L(\mathbf{r}) \quad &\mathbf{r}\in U\\ 0 &\mathbf{r}\notin U\end{cases}$$

$$ \int_{\partial U} G(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'}) \frac{\partial V_{out}(\mathbf{r'})}{\partial n}  -  V_{out}(\mathbf{r'}) \frac{\partial G(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'})}{\partial n} \mathrm{d}s = 
\begin{cases} 0 \quad &\mathbf{r}\in U\\ 
-V_{out}(\mathbf{r}) &\mathbf{r}\notin U\end{cases}$$
where $\mathrm{d}s$ is a surface element.

Then subtracting the two integral equations and applying the boundary conditions:

$$ \int_{\partial U}   V_P(\mathbf{r'}) \frac{\partial G(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'})}{\partial n}  -  G(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'}) \frac{\partial V_P(\mathbf{r'})}{\partial n} \mathrm{d}s = 
\begin{cases} 
V_L(\mathbf{r}) \quad &\mathbf{r}\in U\\ 
V_{out}(\mathbf{r}) &\mathbf{r}\notin U\end{cases}$$
But this seems to contradict the previous two integral equations. Not sure whats going on here.

Comment: Where do you see the contradiction? It's also not very clear what you are after. In principle, a lot of the information about the potential far from the source is captured by multipoles. But the multipoles are still defined by volume integrals over the source. So it seems hard to avoid volume integrals all together.

Comment: The contradiction I see is that the left hand sides of the last set of equations differ from the previous two sets but the right hand sides are identical. Either the first set of equations are wrong or cannot be added together for some reason.

Comment: There must be some very basic miscommunication going on here. The right-hand sides of the three sets of equations are also all (pairwise) different (as functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$). So I really don't see what you are comparing to get a contradiction.

Comment: I'm comparing each region separately. Although now I'm not so sure they contradict